# Convert AVFrame to CVPixelBufferRef to use in function CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, opengl-es-2.0, render

I've a custom video player on iOS platform, I read many threads for performance tuning about using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage API. But, this API is always used with Apple decoders, so as Apple decoders provide CVPixelBufferRef, I can not find any way to convert ffmpeg's AVFrame to CVPixelBufferRef...

Can anyone guide me for this topic?

Is it possible to use CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage API for AVFrames of ffmpeg ? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Well the fromImage part of the method name gives you a clue that you must convert the avframe to a cgimageref first. its a round about way but thats what you have to do. writing directly to a buffer object might be better. but you have to do something like this to get a pixel buffer
https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-beta1/blob/master/FFAVFrames-test/ViewController.m